# Does Apple accept iPhone App with hidden functionalities?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I'm building an iPhone app for a restaurant and would like to implement also an administration area that should only be accessible/viewable to approved users (users will be approved on a server).

Will Apple accept an App which has functionalities hidden to the majority of its users?

Thanks,
Miguel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a "Review Notes" field when you submit your app to the app store. From [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf), "Use this field to give demo account information with full access
to Apple for purposes of reviewing your application." You need to provide detail information here. If you don't do this and Apple finds out later the hidden things, then they will remove the app from the app store. You can safely provide information here, as this information is only available to the review team. User won't see that.

Comment: Thanks very much Taskinoor... I will have a look at the document.

Comment: It might be worth making a separate application or a web-based app for administration stuff. Just don't think you should have functionality included which < 1% of the users will have access too.

Answer (score 0):

They don't like this, and you could get pulled if they found out. When you submit your app you are able to provide information only visible to testers, which could be used to provide a login to your admin service.

Comment: You have to create them a test account (server side). If the details don't login, chances are your binary will be rejected.